# Adding tag in bootstrap tags input dynamically not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, tags

I'm trying to set tags via bootstrap tags input but it's not working and giving following error:

```
TypeError: b.options.itemValue(...) is undefined
```

my code is as follow:

```
$('#searchGeoBottom').tagsinput({
    maxTags: 5,
    delay: 500,
    itemValue: 'value',
    itemText: 'text',
    typeahead: {
        displayKey: 'text',
        source: function (query) {
            if (ajax) {
                ajax.abort();
            }
            var data = {term: query};
            ajax = $.getJSON((baseUrl + "geoSearch"), data);
            return ajax;
        },
        afterSelect: function () {
            this.$element[0].value = '';
        }
    }
});
if (typeof searchGeo != 'undefined' && searchGeo != '') {
    $('#searchGeoBottom').tagsinput('add', searchGeo);
}
```

I've also tried following approach which i found while searching:

```
var elt = $('#searchGeoBottom').tagsinput({....});
elt.tagsinput('add', searchGeo);
```

But it didn't work either, gives elt is not defined or elt is not a function..

Following is the json I'm passing in add function:

```
[{"text":"Lahore. United States","value":4768156}]
```

Comment: can you include a jsfiddle with your question ?

Comment: @AshiqurRahman let me try to include jsfiddle with it, i have also updated my question, please check if it help you understand the issue. Thanks!

Comment: you need to use toString(); try and use tagsinput('add',id:'someID', name:searchGeo.toString())

Answer (score 4):

For those who might have the same problem, try this code:

```
var elt = $('#searchGeoBottom'); // get element
elt.tagsinput({....}); // initialize tagsinput
elt.tagsinput('add', searchGeo[0]); // adding one object at a time and not an array
```